# How to show that $X$ is discrete if I can show that $X + \theta_0/t_0$ where $t_0 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is discrete?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ be a random variable on the probabality space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Let $t_0 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $|\varphi_X(t_0)| = 1$. Then I have to show that $X$ is discrete.

Now by definition there exists $\theta_0 \in (-\pi, \pi]$ such that $\varphi_X(t_0) = e^{-i \theta_0}$. Therefore, $$\varphi_{X + \theta_0/t_0}(t_0) = \mathbb{E}[e^{i t_0 (X + \theta_0 / t_0)}] = \varphi_X(t_0)e^{i \theta_0} = e^{-i \theta_0}e^{i\theta_0} = 1$$
Thus $X + \theta_0/t_0$ is discrete from what I showed an earlier exercise (see maybe my post for that exercise). But how do I now conclude that $X$ is discrete? Can we simply conclude that $X = X + \theta_0/t_0 - \theta_0/t_0$, thus $X$ is discrete?

Comment: sorry, I asked you before to open a new question for this but Im realized now that the answer is fairly trivial. Notice that if the image of a real-valued function $f$ is a discrete set then it is also the image of the function $f+r$, where $r$ is a constant. Said differently: if $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a discrete set then it is also the set $A+r:=\{x+r:x\in A\}$ for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$